# The android custom view error : android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, canvas, view, logcat, android-logcat

I create a custom view.but when i want to use it i have a crash in my app
this is my view:

```
package com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by pooyafayyaz on 3/27/2015.
 */
public class CanvasView extends View {
    ImageView img;
    Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    Canvas drawCanvas;
    Drawable drawable;

    public CanvasView(Context context) {
        super(context);
//        img = img_taken;
    }
    public void setCanvasPath(String bitmap_path) {
        BitmapFactory.Options decode_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        decode_options.inMutable = true;
        canvasBitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmap_path,decode_options);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
//        img.setImageBitmap(canvasBitmap);
        invalidate();
    }
    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (canvasBitmap != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }
}
```

this is the xml file i think the xml cause this errors.but i don't figure out whats the problem.
:

```
<com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.CanvasView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/View"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
```

this is the logcat:

```
03-28 01:40:02.690  16581-16581/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-28 01:40:05.400  16581-16581/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.second}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.CanvasView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.CanvasView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.second.onCreate(second.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.second.onCreate(second.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 01:44:19.180  17830-17830/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-28 01:44:25.750  17830-17830/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.second}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.CanvasView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)

     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.CanvasView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.second.onCreate(second.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.second.onCreate(second.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 01:46:04.460  19120-19120/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-28 01:46:06.290  19120-19120/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.second}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.CanvasView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.CanvasView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.second.onCreate(second.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
```

Comment: you missed a constructor. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086694/how-to-avoid-android-view-inflate-exception)

Comment: Add the constructor which has the attributes as one of the parameters

Comment: @Blackbelt
 I called this class from another activity with             CanvasView c =new CanvasView(this);

so how to call it with new attr?

Comment: @JayeshElamgodil what is the second parameter?what is for?AttributeSet attrs?

Comment: Check the link I posted in the first comment

Comment: @rowss check the link posted by @Blackbelt. And if you are doing `CanvasView c =new CanvasView(this);`, why do you need to have it in the xml?

Comment: @vinitius yes.i should have second parameter.but i dont know how to pass second parameter frome another class?
CanvasView c =new CanvasView(this,?????);

Comment: @rowss you will not use the second parameter. The system uses it when inflating your class from some xml. Again, why do you need the view in the xml if you are creating the view yourself in code?

Comment: If you call this xml using setContentView or by using the inflater, you wouldn't need the second parameter. It would be passed by the system.

Comment: hey is your problem solved because I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

to implement the constructor expected by the layout inflation framework.

Answer (score 0):

If youre using a custom View. Android expects an AttributeSet for the internal LayoutInflater.

So just add the AttributeSet to your CustomView Constructor and in its super(context,attributeSet) method.

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet{
   super(context,attributeSet);
}
```