# Extended ExpandableListView infalting error

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, android-inflate

I've tried to extend the ExpandableListView class, but getting :

```
android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #30: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.myapp.ExtendedExpandableListView
```

My custom ExpandableListView :

```
public class ExtendedExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {

    public ExtendedExpandableListView(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        try {
            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e("LOG", "Ignore list view error ->" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

the element as defined in the layout's xml :

```
<com.myapp.ExtendedExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/customListViewElement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:showDividers="middle" >
</com.myapp.ExtendedExpandableListView>
```

inflating in the fragment :

```
myListView = (ExtendedExpandableListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.customListViewElement);
```

Comment: Check your package name. ExtendedExpandableListView is in com.myapp?

Comment: package="com.myapp". Yep, it is.

Comment: Clean the build

Comment: why you call super(context, null); just call super(context) instead.

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086694/how-to-avoid-android-view-inflate-exception)

Comment: Tried calling super(context) instead of super(context,null). Then cleaned the build. It still crashes though.. 
@Blackbelt, am I missing additional constructors? I didn't understand the solution there

Comment: yes, you have to add that constructor

Comment: @Blackbelt you were right, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in XML

```
<com.myapp.ExtendedExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/customListViewElement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:showDividers="middle"
</com.myapp.ExtendedExpandableListView>
```

You have included `>` before closing tag use the above one with remove `>` tag at the end